# Opening BizTalk files

Tags: visual-studio-2008, biztalk

it's been a while since I used BizTalk. But I want to put some screenshots of previous biztalk solutions in my portfolio. However I don't have BizTalk anymore. Is there a way I can open the solutions in visual studio 2008 and take screenshots without installing BizTalk Server?

They're BizTalk Server 2006 R2 files, I tried downloading it but I couldn't find a place to download it for free.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. For opening BizTalk 2006R2 files you need Visual Studio 2005 and BizTalk 2006R2 development tools available on BizTalk 2006R2 installation DVD. These tools will install all necessary designer tools to VS and they are only compatible with version 2005.